# Python tool for time-frequency analysis

Tags: fft, python, wavelet, time-frequency, eeg

I am trying to perform time-frequency analyses using the PyWavelets (pywt) toolkit for python. My ultimate goal is to perform time-frequency analyses for EEG signals but I am starting with something simpler.
For a sanity test, I am creating a simple signal of length 2 seconds, with sample rate 250Hz, containing 2 sine waves - one of 3Hz and one of 10Hz. I would like to create a time-frequency plot that has two horizontal lines - one for the 3Hz and one for the 10Hz, which looks like this (only for illustration purposes):
[image]

For this purpose, I tried using code from the following tutorial : http://ataspinar.com/2018/12/21/a-guide-for-using-the-wavelet-transform-in-machine-learning/, specifically in section 3.1 of the tutorial.

This is a minimal example based on the code from the tutorial:

```
from UliEngineering.SignalProcessing.Simulation import sine_wave
import pywt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_wavelet(time, signal, scales,
             waveletname='cmor',
             cmap=plt.cm.seismic,
             title='Wavelet Transform (Power Spectrum) of signal',
             ylabel='Period (seconds)',
             xlabel='Time'):
    dt = time[1] - time[0]
    [coefficients, frequencies] = pywt.cwt(signal, scales, waveletname, dt)
    power = (abs(coefficients)) ** 2
    period = 1. / frequencies
    levels = [0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8]
    contourlevels = np.log2(levels)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
    im = ax.contourf(time, np.log2(period), np.log2(power), contourlevels, 
    extend='both', cmap=cmap)

    ax.set_title(title, fontsize=20)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel, fontsize=18)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel, fontsize=18)

    yticks = 2 ** np.arange(np.ceil(np.log2(period.min())), 
    np.ceil(np.log2(period.max())))
    ax.set_yticks(np.log2(yticks))
    ax.set_yticklabels(yticks)
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    ax.set_ylim(ylim[0], -1)

    cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.5, 0.03, 0.25])
    fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax, orientation="vertical")
    plt.show()

def generate_sine_wave(length, samplerate, frequencies):
    wave = np.zeros(int(length * samplerate))
    for frequency in frequencies:
        wave += sine_wave(frequency=frequency, samplerate=samplerate, 
        length=length)
    return wave


signal = generate_sine_wave(2, 250, [3, 10])
N = len(signal)
t0 = 0
dt = 1/250
time = np.arange(0, N) * dt +t0


scales = np.arange(1, 256)
plot_wavelet(time, signal, scales)
```

This plot from this code doesn't give me the plot I want, it looks like this:
[image]

I tried many modifications for this code but none gave me the result I want. And there are a couple of things I don't understand about the code:
- What is the purpose of the "period" variable in the "plot_wavelet" function and how do I make the y-axis show frequencies instead?
- What is the purpose of the "scales" variable?
- How do I define a frequency range that I want the result to include?
- How do I use linear scaling for the frequencies instead of log scale?

If anyone can give some pointers regarding this I will be very happy. Been spending some time trying to plot normal time-frequency plots but still haven't been able to find a python tool that performs this simple plot which makes sense to me.
Thank you,
Elad

Answer (score 1):

You can find a nice tutorial for time-frequency analysis in Numerical python by Johansson, chapter 17. link to github [repository](https://github.com/Ziaeemehr/signal_processing/tree/master/Numerical_Python_johansson).

You can also check the [scipy.signal.spectrogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from scipy.fft import fftshift
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate a test signal, a 2 Vrms sine wave whose frequency
# is slowly modulated around 3kHz, corrupted by white noise
# of exponentially decreasing magnitude sampled at 10 kHz.

fs = 1e4
N = 1e5
amp = 2 * np.sqrt(2)
noise_power = 0.01 * fs / 2
time = np.arange(N) / float(fs)
mod = 500 * np.cos(2 * np.pi * 0.25 * time)
carrier = amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 3e3 * time + mod)
noise = np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(noise_power), size=time.shape)
noise *= np.exp(-time / 5)
x = carrier + noise

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(8, 7))

f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, fs)
ax[0].pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
ax[0].set_ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
ax[0].set_xlabel('Time [sec]')

# Note, if using output that is not one sided, then use the following:
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, fs, return_onesided=False)
ax[1].pcolormesh(t, fftshift(f), fftshift(Sxx, axes=0))
ax[1].set_ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
ax[1].set_xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.savefig("fig.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]